# Set the default font style, color, and size for an xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

The app I'm working on has a particular color scheme, so I was wondering if it is possible to set a "default" background color, text color, and font size so that every time I create a new view, or label in Interface Builder I don't have to change all of these parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 5, there is the `UIAppearance` protocol that all of the standard UI elements implement.  Using the "Appearance proxy" you can set the appearance for ALL objects of that type in a given application.  More information can be found in the incredibly helpful and informative WWDC '12 session on ["Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216)

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a DanFViewController (subclassed from UIViewController) that already has the specific background color, text color, font size, etc. you need and then derive all your app's custom views from that?

That's what I do in my own apps where clients are expecting a certain look & feel for all the views.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, but it would still require me setting those parameters onto every text field, uilabel, text view, etc. that gets added to each view

Comment: you can also set those parameters in your DanFViewController's "viewDidLoad" method.  It doesn't *have* to be in Xcode's Interface Builder.

Comment: I meant for each new label I add, I would have to do `newLabel.font = self.defaultFont;` or whatever the appropriate set font method for labels is, right?

Comment: If all those labels have to look the same, create a DanFLabel (subclassed from UILabel) and set the font there, too.